# How to deal with Missing Not at Random Data for k-means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, missing-data

I am running k-means clustering on a customer dataset. One of the available demographic fields is inferred homevalue, represented as an integer. 
This field has value 0 when it's inferred that the customer is not a homeowner at all (they are more likely a renter, live with relatives, etc).
I'm struggling to think of a good way to treat this value.

Does it make sense to keep this value as 0? Then my understanding is that the algorithm will interpret this as someone who doesn't own property is closely related to someone who owns an extremely low value property which doesn't seem intuitively right.

Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: I think your question is not clear to me. What do you mean the value of homevalue  is zero? What else it can be? Is it categorical then? It is best if you give a few lines of your dataset!

Comment: Your attributes will likely have very different scale already. Try to think through what you are actually computing: does this make any sense for your application? What is the appropriate way of scaling the data, and *why*? Or are you just using k-means because it is the only thing you know? How can you know if a result is really good, or just "average"?

Comment: The solutions mentioned above seem to be really helpful.
But personally, would be really helpful to get a small sample dataset, if zou could provide one.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a case of missing not at random, the best thing to do is create a new feature. You can add a new feature which has value 0 if the person doesn't own a house and 1 if he owns a house.

Also K-means is usually not used for clustering. You could go for other algorithms such as Hierarchical or DBScan.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two approaches you can take:

## 1) Square the 'homevalue'

Assuming that `homevalue` is a `numeric` you can square this value.

Then, you will increase the difference between $0$-valued homes and low-valued homes. Further, it will make the difference between high-valued homes to low-valued homes also larger.

## 2) Split into two features

You can also split this information into two different features:

- Home value $v$, where $v \in \mathbb{R}^+$
- Owns a home $h$, where $h \in \{true, false\}$ and $h = \substack{false, \quad if \, v \, equals \, 0\\true, \quad \ otherwise}$

This way, your model has a way to explicitly distinguish between people that own or not a home.

Then hopefully you have another feature indicating the lifestyle or earnings of a person that doesn't own a home.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but squaring doesn't seem motivated at all.

Comment: Adding a flag 'helps' assuming you scale the inputs too, but you're still left with the problem that "0" is interpreted as a home value. I'd guess the best you can do is impute a mean value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two features differentiating between a costumer is a homeowner or not being that feature binary and other indicating the home value, with values only for homeowners, N/A in case that is not a homeowner. It doesn't make sense otherwise. The value for a non-owner of his house is not 0, it's just inexistent which is not the same.

If you want to differentiate between homeowners and not homeowners is okay but you're not going to be able to compare homevalues for the reason mentioned above. Is better to use a proxy variable instead like equity assests which is a continuous variable who makes sense to compare between all costumers (Could be difficult to find such proxy).

Finally you used K-Means for clustering but is not suitable for categorical variables. K-Means use the centroids to group all points by a distance criteria, then do the mean of all this points and assign that mean to the centroid repeating until convergence. Categorical variables don't work well with distances because there is not a direct relation between those distances.